# is there any way that we can develop application in .net for iphone

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, xamarin.ios

can we develop application for iphone in visual studio itself are there any emulator for testing it that is compatible with visual studio

Comment: Is it really necessary to ask minor variations of the same question three times? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599634/is-there-any-way-that-we-can-develop-application-in-net-for-iphone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599820/development-of-iphone-applications

Comment: You should also consider selecting an answer to the questions that you ask.

Answer (score 15):

You can use Mono in the iphone environment to develop apps in a C# / .NET environment. - https://www.xamarin.com is one example of someone doing that.

Comment: +1 ..I didn't know it .. I did searched for something like this before didn't found any

Comment: Will it run on a non-jailbroken iPhone?

Comment: Absolutely. It is an Apple approved method of doing things.

Comment: **Update on this:** This status may have changed, waiting for Apple to actually enforce the new policy (or back down, hopefully), SO thread is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604033/is-monotouch-now-banned-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 4):

Monodevelop 2.2 Beta has a setup for Windows. [Download](http://monodevelop.com/Download)

But if you want to develop for the iPhone (with [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/)) you are required to have an Intel Mac (otherwise you couldn't run the neccesary Apple tools).

Depending on WHAT you want to do you could also use [Unity for the iPhone](http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/iphone-1.5) which is also Mono/.Net based.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, Mono is the way.

There isn't a way at present to do straightforward development in Visual studio, however this will be coming soon as a VS Addin, which was discussed on Hanselminutes.

There is a Mono IDE though, called [monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)

[Link to Mono Podcast from Hanselminutes here](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=199)

Comment: with airplay, you can use visual studio

Answer (score 3):

You can use [xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com) (previously monotouch)

Comment: The only problem with this being that it will not be of any use on Windows, even of you do install MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Mono for that.
Novell released a commercial product: MonoTouch

Now it's https://www.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 1):

You will still need the official iPhone SDK and OSX, from [MonoTouch Requirements](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Installation):

> To begin using MonoTouch, you will need to have:
>
> - Apple's iPhone SDK 3.0 or higher, available from Apple's iPhone Dev Center.
> - An Intel Mac computer running MacOS 10.5 or 10.6 (Leopard or Snow Leopard).
> - The latest release of Mono for OSX

So it's not exactly a free lunch yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Besides using [Monotouch](http://monotouch.net/), there is no other way to do it in **.NET**.

If you are not willing to use OBJ-C's native API for iPhone you could also consider [FLASH](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashcs5/appsfor_iphone/).

Comment: @Rob I never said flash works in iPhone. I said you can USE FLASH and ACTION SCRIPT 3 to develop FOR the iPhone. Check the link I posted out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Airplay SDK: http://www.airplaysdk.com/

You can develop with Visual Studio and target the iPhone for free. If you target other mobile platforms, the pricing changes. You will still need a Macintosh to sign your iPhone package, but all the development / testing can be done in C++ in Visual Studio on Windows.