# iphone application using xcode

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there any way that we can develop application in .net for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599634/is-there-any-way-that-we-can-develop-application-in-net-for-iphone)

can xcode be used to develop iphone applications using .net and is it compatible with windows

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599634/is-there-any-way-that-we-can-develop-application-in-net-for-iphone

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Mono Touch](http://monotouch.net/). It lets you use .NET-style languages and tools to develop iPhone apps.

However, it won't be compatible with Windows.  Mono Touch is basically a wrapper over Cocoa Touch.  You still have to use Xcode (on a Mac) to build and distribute apps developed with Mono Touch.