# Are wrapper classes banned in the iPhone OS Developer Agreement?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am a little confused after reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604033/is-monotouch-now-banned-on-the-iphone) on the revisions to the iPhone Developer Agreement.

While it lists the languages that are permitted, I don't understand what classifies as falling under what is banned.

**Does this include wrapper classes? What if the code is written in Objective C but is not an official Apple class/library?**

I'm wondering about things like:

- [Three20 from Facebook](http://github.com/facebook/three20)
- SQLite Wrappers such as [this one](http://th30z.netsons.org/2008/11/objective-c-sqlite-wrapper/)
- Charting / Graphing Libraries

If anyone could clarify this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries and wrappers are allowed under the terms of clause 3.3.1, as long as they

- are written in C, Objective-C, C++ or JavaScript
- adhere to all the other SDK agreement clauses (e.g. do not implement an interpreter for a language).

Three20 and the SQL-wrapper are all ok to use and are used in plenty of projects.

> Applications may only use Documented APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any private APIs.

This refers to the APIs provides by Apple. You may only use Apple's code/frameworks with the documented functions, not with any private functions that may be present but not documented.

Answer (score 0):

The revision states that **Applications that link to Documented APIs through an intermediary translation or compatibility layer or tool are prohibited**, so this would only affect tools that translate code from other languages/platforms (Monotouch, flash-to-iphone, etc). So you should be ok, I used Three20 before and have seen other apps in the app store which use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed wrapper class which will be very helpful to you.

First download latest SDK of Facebook.

Create one class named as "FacebookHelper"

Add following code in .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"

@protocol FBApiCallDelegate;

typedef enum FBApiCallType
{
FBApiCallNone = 0,
FBApiCallGetUserInfo = 1,
FBApiCallGetUserFriend = 2,
FBApiCallPostMessage = 3,
FBApiCallPostPicture = 4,
FBApiCallShareLink = 5,
FBApiCallPostAll = 6,
FBApiCallPostMessageFriendWall = 7

} FBApiCallType;

@interface FacebookHelper : NSObject<FBRequestDelegate, FBDialogDelegate, FBSessionDelegate> {
Facebook *objFacebook;
NSArray *arrPermission;

id<FBApiCallDelegate> apiCallDelegate;
FBApiCallType currentApiCallType;

NSString *strMessage;
NSString *strUrlTitle;
NSString *strUrl;
NSString *strCaption;
NSString *strPictureUrl;
UIImage *image;
}
@property(readonly) Facebook *objFacebook;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<FBApiCallDelegate> apiCallDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) FBApiCallType currentApiCallType;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strMessage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strUrlTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strCaption;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strPictureUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;


+ (FacebookHelper *) sharedInstance;
- (void)releaseObjects;

//Store Authentication
- (void)storeAuthData:(NSString *)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate *)expiresAt;
- (void)removeAuthData;

//Public Methods
-(BOOL)isLoggedIn;
-(void)loginToFacebook;
-(void)logoutFromFacebook;

//Facebook Methods
-(void)getUserInfo;                 //Get User Info
-(void)getUserFriends;              //Get User's Friend List
-(void)postMessageToWall;           //Post Message to FB Wall
-(void)postPictureToWall;           //Post Picture to FB Wall
-(void)shareLinkOnWall;             //Share Link on FB Wall
-(void)postAllToWall;               //Post All - Message, Link, Caption, PhotoUrl
-(void)postMessageToFriendWall;     //Post Message to Friend Wall


//String Methods
- (BOOL)isEmptyString:(NSString *)strValue;
- (NSString *) trimWhiteSpace:(NSString *)strValue;

// Default AlertView
-(void)showAlertView:(NSString *)pstrTitle withMessage:(NSString *)pstrMessage delegate:(id)pDelegate;

@end

@protocol FBApiCallDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

//Get User Info Delegate
-(void)finishUserInfoResponse:(id)result;
-(void)failedUserInfoResponse:(NSError *)error;

//Get User's Friend List
-(void)finishUserFriendResponse:(id)result;
-(void)failedUserFriendResponse:(NSError *)error;

//Post Message to FB Wall Delegate
-(void)finishPostMessageResponse:(id)result;
-(void)failedPostMessageResponse:(NSError *)error;

//Post Picture to FB Wall
-(void)finishPostPictureResponse:(id)result;
-(void)failedPostPictureResponse:(NSError *)error;

//Share Link on FB Wall
-(void)finishShareLinkResponse:(id)result;
-(void)failedShareLinkResponse:(NSError *)error;

//Post All - Message, Link, Caption, PhotoUrl
-(void)finishPostAllResponse:(id)result;
-(void)failedPostAllResponse:(NSError *)error;

//Post Message to Friend Wall Delegate
-(void)finishPostMsgFriendWallResponse:(id)result;
-(void)failedPostMsgFriendWallResponse:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

Add following code in .m file:

```
#import "FacebookHelper.h"

@implementation FacebookHelper

@synthesize objFacebook;
@synthesize apiCallDelegate, currentApiCallType;
@synthesize strMessage, strUrlTitle, strUrl, strCaption, strPictureUrl, image;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Singleton Variables
static FacebookHelper *singletonHelper = nil;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Singleton Methods
- (id)init {
if (!g_kFacebookAppId) {
    NSLog(@"%@", msgFBAppIDMissing);
    exit(1);
    return nil;
}

if ((self = [super init])) {
    arrPermission =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"read_stream", @"publish_stream", @"offline_access", @"email", @"read_friendlists", @"friends_birthday",nil] retain];
}

return self;
}
+ (FacebookHelper *)sharedInstance {
@synchronized(self) {
    if (singletonHelper == nil) {
        [[self alloc] init]; // assignment not done here
    }
}
return singletonHelper;
}
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
@synchronized(self) {
    if (singletonHelper == nil) {
        singletonHelper = [super allocWithZone:zone];
        // assignment and return on first allocation
        return singletonHelper;
    }
}
// on subsequent allocation attempts return nil
return nil;
}
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
return self;
}
- (id)retain {
return self;
}
- (unsigned)retainCount {
return UINT_MAX;  // denotes an object that cannot be released
}
//- (void)release {
- (void)dealloc {
[self releaseObjects];

[super dealloc];
}
- (id)autorelease {
return self;
}
- (void)releaseObjects {
[self.strMessage release];
[self.strUrlTitle release];
[self.strUrl release];
[self.strCaption release];
[self.strPictureUrl release];
[self.image release];

[objFacebook release];
objFacebook = nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark FBDelegate(FBSessionDelegate) Methods
/**
 * Called when the user has logged in successfully.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogin {
NSLog(@"FB login OK");
[self storeAuthData:objFacebook.accessToken expiresAt:objFacebook.expirationDate];

switch(currentApiCallType)
{
    case FBApiCallGetUserInfo:
        [self getUserInfo];
        break;
    case FBApiCallGetUserFriend:
        [self getUserFriends];
        break;
    case FBApiCallPostMessage:
        [self postMessageToWall];
        break;
    case FBApiCallPostPicture:
        [self postPictureToWall];
        break;
    case FBApiCallShareLink:
        [self shareLinkOnWall];
        break;
    case FBApiCallPostAll:
        [self postAllToWall];
        break;
    case FBApiCallPostMessageFriendWall:
        [self postMessageToFriendWall];
        break;

}
}
/**
 * Called when the user canceled the authorization dialog.
 */
-(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled {
NSLog(@"FB did not login");
[self removeAuthData];
}
/**
 * Called when the request logout has succeeded.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogout { 
NSLog(@"FB logout OK");
[self removeAuthData];
}
-(void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString *)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate *)expiresAt {
NSLog(@"token extended");
[self storeAuthData:accessToken expiresAt:expiresAt];
}
/**
 * Called when the session has expired.
 */
- (void)fbSessionInvalidated {
[self showAlertView:msgFBSessionInvalidateTitle withMessage:msgFBSessionInvalidateMessage delegate:nil];
[self fbDidLogout];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark FBRequestDelegate Methods
/**
 * Called when the Facebook API request has returned a response. This callback
 * gives you access to the raw response. It's called before
 * (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result,
 * which is passed the parsed response object.
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
NSLog(@"received response");
}
/**
 * Called when a request returns and its response has been parsed into
 * an object. The resulting object may be a dictionary, an array, a string,
 * or a number, depending on the format of the API response. If you need access
 * to the raw response, use:
 *
 * (void)request:(FBRequest *)request
 *      didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
NSLog(@"FB request OK");
switch(currentApiCallType)
{
    case FBApiCallGetUserInfo:
        if([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishUserInfoResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate finishUserInfoResponse:result];
        break;

    case FBApiCallGetUserFriend:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishUserFriendResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate finishUserFriendResponse:result];
        break;

    case FBApiCallPostMessage:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishPostMessageResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate finishPostMessageResponse:result];
        break;

    case FBApiCallPostPicture:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishPostPictureResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate finishPostPictureResponse:result];
        break;

    case FBApiCallShareLink:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishShareLinkResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate finishShareLinkResponse:result];
        break;

    case FBApiCallPostAll:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishPostAllResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate finishPostAllResponse:result];
        break;

    case FBApiCallPostMessageFriendWall:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishPostMsgFriendWallResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate finishPostMsgFriendWallResponse:result];
        break;
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

currentApiCallType = FBApiCallNone;
}
/**
 * Called when an error prevents the Facebook API request from completing
 * successfully.
 */
/*- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"FB error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}*/
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Err message: %@", [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error_msg"]);
/*NSLog(@"Err code: %@", [error code]);
NSLog(@"Err desc: %@", [error description]);
NSLog(@"FB error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);*/

switch(currentApiCallType)
{
    case FBApiCallGetUserInfo:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(failedUserInfoResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate failedUserInfoResponse:error];
        break;

    case FBApiCallGetUserFriend:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(failedUserFriendResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate failedUserFriendResponse:error];
        break;

    case FBApiCallPostMessage:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(failedPostMessageResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate failedPostMessageResponse:error];
        break;

    case FBApiCallPostPicture:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(failedPostPictureResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate failedPostPictureResponse:error];
        break;

    case FBApiCallShareLink:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(failedShareLinkResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate failedShareLinkResponse:error];
        break;

    case FBApiCallPostAll:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(failedPostAllResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate failedPostAllResponse:error];

    case FBApiCallPostMessageFriendWall:
        if ([self.apiCallDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(failedPostMsgFriendWallResponse:)])
            [self.apiCallDelegate failedPostMsgFriendWallResponse:error];
        break;
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

currentApiCallType = FBApiCallNone;
}
/**
 * Called when a UIServer Dialog successfully return.
 */
- (void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog {
NSLog(@"Published successfully on FB");
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Store/Remove Authentication 
- (void)storeAuthData:(NSString *)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate *)expiresAt {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:accessToken forKey:g_kFacebookAccessToken];
[defaults setObject:expiresAt forKey:g_kFacebookExpirationDate];
[defaults synchronize];
}
- (void)removeAuthData{
// Remove saved authorization information if it exists and it is
// ok to clear it (logout, session invalid, app unauthorized)
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults removeObjectForKey:g_kFacebookAccessToken];
[defaults removeObjectForKey:g_kFacebookExpirationDate];
[defaults synchronize];

/*
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:g_kFacebookAccessToken];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:g_kFacebookExpirationDate];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];*/
/*
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:g_kFacebookAccessToken];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:g_kFacebookExpirationDate];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];*/
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Public Methods
-(BOOL)isLoggedIn
{
if(objFacebook == nil)
    objFacebook = [[[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:g_kFacebookAppId andDelegate:self] retain];

NSString *strAccessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:g_kFacebookAccessToken];
NSLog(@"Access Token = %@", strAccessToken);

//if(![strAccessToken isEmptyString])
if(![self isEmptyString:strAccessToken])
{
    objFacebook.accessToken    = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:g_kFacebookAccessToken];
    objFacebook.expirationDate = (NSDate *) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:g_kFacebookExpirationDate];
}

if([objFacebook isSessionValid])
    return YES;
else
    return NO;

return NO;
}
-(void)loginToFacebook
{
if(![self isLoggedIn])
    [objFacebook authorize:arrPermission];
}
-(void)logoutFromFacebook {
[objFacebook logout:self];

[self removeAuthData];
[self releaseObjects];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Facebook Methods
-(void)getUserInfo
{
currentApiCallType = FBApiCallGetUserInfo;
if([self isLoggedIn])
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"name,picture",@"fields",nil];
    [objFacebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
else
    [self loginToFacebook];
}
-(void)getUserFriends
{
currentApiCallType = FBApiCallGetUserFriend;
if([self isLoggedIn])
{   
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture,id,name,birthday,link,gender,last_name,first_name",@"fields",nil];
    [objFacebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
else
    [self loginToFacebook];
}
-(void)postMessageToWall
{
currentApiCallType = FBApiCallPostMessage;
if([self isLoggedIn])
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [params setObject:@"status" forKey:@"type"];
    [params setObject:self.strMessage forKey:@"message"];
    [objFacebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
}
else
    [self loginToFacebook];
}
-(void)postPictureToWall
{
currentApiCallType = FBApiCallPostPicture;
if([self isLoggedIn])
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [params setObject:self.image forKey:@"source"];
    [params setObject:self.strMessage forKey:@"message"];
    [objFacebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
}
else
    [self loginToFacebook];
}
-(void)shareLinkOnWall
{
currentApiCallType = FBApiCallShareLink;
if([self isLoggedIn])
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [params setObject:@"link" forKey:@"type"];
    [params setObject:self.strUrl forKey:@"link"];
    [params setObject:self.strMessage forKey:@"description"];
    [objFacebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
}
else
    [self loginToFacebook];
}
-(void)postAllToWall
{
currentApiCallType = FBApiCallPostAll;
if([self isLoggedIn])
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [params setObject:self.strMessage forKey:@"description"];
    [params setObject:self.strUrlTitle forKey:@"name"];
    [params setObject:self.strUrl forKey:@"link"];
    [params setObject:self.strCaption forKey:@"caption"];
    [params setObject:self.strPictureUrl forKey:@"picture"];
    [objFacebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
}
else
    [self loginToFacebook];
}
-(void)postMessageToFriendWall
{
currentApiCallType = FBApiCallPostMessageFriendWall;
if([self isLoggedIn])
{
    NSString *strGraphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", @"100002305497328"];
    //NSString *strGraphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", @"100002560928461"];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [params setObject:self.strMessage forKey:@"message"];
    [objFacebook requestWithGraphPath:strGraphPath andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
}
else
    [self loginToFacebook];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark String Methods
- (BOOL)isEmptyString:(NSString *)strValue
{   
NSString *copy;

if (strValue == nil)
    return (YES);

if ([strValue isEqualToString:@""])
    return (YES);

if ([strValue isEqualToString:@"(null)"])
    return (YES);

copy = [[strValue copy] autorelease];

//if ([[copy trimWhiteSpace] isEqualToString: @""])
if ([[self trimWhiteSpace:copy] isEqualToString: @""])
    return (YES);

return (NO);
} /*stringIsEmpty*/
- (NSString *) trimWhiteSpace:(NSString *)strValue 
{
NSMutableString *s = [[strValue mutableCopy] autorelease];
CFStringTrimWhitespace ((CFMutableStringRef) s);
return (NSString *) [[s copy] autorelease];
} /*trimWhiteSpace*/

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Default AlertView
-(void)showAlertView:(NSString *)pstrTitle withMessage:(NSString *)pstrMessage delegate:(id)pDelegate
{
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:pstrTitle message:pstrMessage delegate:pDelegate cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];    
}

@end
```

That's it. Now our Facebook wrapper class is ready.

Create 3 below class for better organization.

FacebookGlobal.h

Add below data:

```
#define g_kFacebookAppId        @"<Your AppID>"
#define g_kFacebookAppSecret    @"<Your Secret>"


#define g_kPostMessage          @"<Message>"
#define g_kPostUrlTitle         @"<Title>"
#define g_kPostUrl              @"<Url>"
#define g_kPostCaption          @"<Caption>"
#define g_kPostPictureUrl       @"<Image Url>"
```

FacebookKey.h

Add below data:

```
#define g_kFacebookAccessToken      @"FBAccessTokenKey"
#define g_kFacebookExpirationDate   @"FBExpirationDateKey"
```

FacebookMessage.h

Add below data:

```
//AppID Missing 
#define msgFBAppIDMissing @"Missing AppID"

//Session Invalidated
#define msgFBSessionInvalidateTitle @"Auth Exception"
#define msgFBSessionInvalidateMessage @"Your session has expired."
```

Import below files in your .pch files:

```
#import "FacebookGlobal.h"
#import "FacebookKey.h"
#import "FacebookMessage.h"

#import "FacebookHelper.h"
```

Now, you are ready for use.

In your view controller, add below delegate:

```
<FBApiCallDelegate>
```

In your view controller .m file, add below methods to call as well delegate:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
/*
FacebookHelper *fbHelper = [FacebookHelper sharedInstance];
[fbHelper logoutFromFacebook];
*/


//Get User Info
FacebookHelper *fbHelper = [FacebookHelper sharedInstance];
fbHelper.apiCallDelegate = self;
[fbHelper getUserInfo];


/*
//Get User's Friend List
FacebookHelper *fbHelper = [FacebookHelper sharedInstance];
fbHelper.apiCallDelegate = self;
[fbHelper getUserFriends];
*/

/*
//Post Message to FB Wall
FacebookHelper *fbHelper = [FacebookHelper sharedInstance];
fbHelper.apiCallDelegate = self;
fbHelper.strMessage = g_kPostMessage;
[fbHelper postMessageToWall];
*/

/*
//Post Picture to FB Wall
FacebookHelper *fbHelper = [FacebookHelper sharedInstance];
fbHelper.apiCallDelegate = self;
fbHelper.strMessage = g_kPostMessage;
fbHelper.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"postPicture.jpg"];
[fbHelper postPictureToWall];
*/

/*
//Share Link on FB Wall
FacebookHelper *fbHelper = [FacebookHelper sharedInstance];
fbHelper.apiCallDelegate = self;
fbHelper.strUrl = g_kPostUrl;
fbHelper.strMessage = g_kPostMessage;
[fbHelper shareLinkOnWall];
*/

/*
//Post All to FB Wall
FacebookHelper *fbHelper = [FacebookHelper sharedInstance];
fbHelper.apiCallDelegate = self;
fbHelper.strMessage = g_kPostMessage;
fbHelper.strUrlTitle = g_kPostUrlTitle;
fbHelper.strUrl = g_kPostUrl;
fbHelper.strCaption = g_kPostCaption;
fbHelper.strPictureUrl = g_kPostPictureUrl;
[fbHelper postAllToWall];
 */

/*
//Post Message to Friend Wall
FacebookHelper *fbHelper = [FacebookHelper sharedInstance];
fbHelper.apiCallDelegate = self;
fbHelper.strMessage = g_kPostMessage;
[fbHelper postMessageToFriendWall];
*/
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Get User Info Delegate
-(void)finishUserInfoResponse:(id)result{
NSLog(@"UserInfo response successed!");
NSLog(@"%@", result);

}
-(void)failedUserInfoResponse:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"UserInfo response failed!");
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Get User's Friend List
-(void)finishUserFriendResponse:(id)result{
NSLog(@"User FriendList response successed!");
NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
-(void)failedUserFriendResponse:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"User FriendList response failed!");
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Post Message to FB Wall Delegate
-(void)finishPostMessageResponse:(id)result{
NSLog(@"Post message successed!");
NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
-(void)failedPostMessageResponse:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"Post message failed!");
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Post Picture to FB Wall
-(void)finishPostPictureResponse:(id)result{
NSLog(@"Post picture successed!");
NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
-(void)failedPostPictureResponse:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"Post picture failed!");
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Share Link on FB Wall
-(void)finishShareLinkResponse:(id)result{
NSLog(@"Share link successed!");
NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
-(void)failedShareLinkResponse:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"Share link failed!");
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Post All - Message, Link, Caption, PhotoUrl
-(void)finishPostAllResponse:(id)result{
NSLog(@"Post all successed!");
NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
-(void)failedPostAllResponse:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"Post all failed!");
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Post Message to Friend Wall Delegate
-(void)finishPostMsgFriendWallResponse:(id)result{
NSLog(@"Post message to friend wall successed!");
NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
-(void)failedPostMsgFriendWallResponse:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"Post message to friend wall failed!");
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Enjoy.